# How to make a Generic Grid with CRUD operations on multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, generics, grid, crud

How to make a grid as generic with CRUD operations and respective validations.

Here the generic means generalising the BL and as well as the UI.

I have 10 tables where the bussiness logic and the UI implementation is same. But I dont want to actually like to create 10 repositories methods for them and also 10 aspx pages to populate the data.

In the BL, is there a way to get the List and do CRUD operations. I have researched and  had an idea to implement this using Reflection for Read operation But not sure on Update/Insert.

In the UI, as of now I am populating data in Grid and Insert/Update in popup with user control. So I have an idea to use MVP, but not too sure how to implement this?

Any discussions / suggestions would be helpful!